# hide() and show() methods in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how should i get back the tables that have been hidden using this piece of code:

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {
        var tblId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
       // alert(tblId);
       var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this table?");
        if(ans == true)
            $("#" + tblId).hide();
        //else exit();
    });
```

the html content is:

```
<li class="ui-state-default"  id="first"><span style="float:right;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><br/>




            <table class="rounded-corner">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Trial Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>155$</td>
            <td>12/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Carrina</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Hosting Pack</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Duo Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>745$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Alavasti Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>




            </li>

            <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="second"><span style="float:right;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><br/>
                <table class="rounded-corner">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Trial Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>155$</td>
            <td>12/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Carrina</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Hosting Pack</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Duo Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>745$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Alavasti Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
            </li>
```

Comment: When do you want to show it??

Comment: FWIW: `if(ans == true)` can be written `if(ans)`, which is usually clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use in following way

```
$("#" + tblId).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You write code that calls `show` with the same value in the `tblId` variable:

```
$("#" + tblId).show();
```

How you *call* that code is up to you; obviously it will have to be accessible via some element not within the table itself, as the table is hidden.

If I'm reading your HTML correctly, the icon "removing" (hiding) the table is outside the table, so you could change your handler to this:

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {
    var tblId, tbl, ans;

    tblId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    tbl = $("#" + tblId);
    if (tbl.is(":visible")) {
        // It's showing
        ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to hide this table?");
    } else {
        // It's not showing
        ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to show this table?");
    }
    // alert(tblId);
    if(ans) {
        tbl.toggle(); // toggle hides or shows, depending
    }
});
```

If you did that, you'd probably also want to change the icon being shown (so it suggests "show" when the table is hidden).